# Excitement level in OCEAN model

Tags: personality, psychology

So, I would like to know what facet regulates these behaviours / cahracteristics of a person:

- How loud and fast-talking they are (on average).
- Their excitement level (on average).

Excitement seeking [(1)](http://www.testsonthenet.com/Factors-facets.htm) [(2)](http://www.timothy-judge.com/documents/2013-31562-001.pdf) [(3)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-agreeableness) [(4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensation_seeking) is defined as facet that tells how much a person seeks excitement, but does it tells how much a person is excited on average? And if not then what facet tells that?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an aspect of extraversion. I.e., loud and fast talking sounds like gregariousness and assertiveness.  In general, extraverts are also more active and expressive.

For example, the NEO-PI-R has facets of extraversion as follows:
(E1) Warmth (E2)
Gregariousness (E3) Assertiveness (E4) Activity (E5)
Excitement-Seeking (E6) Positive Emotions

Fast talking might also be linked to intelligence.